# R code line graph that indicates point with highest y-value

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a graph in R code that is coded like this:

```
Graph<-ggplot(data=df, aes(x=Frame,y=Score)) +
   geom_line()
   geom_abline()
```

Is there anything I could add to this code that would create a marker indicating the point on the graph that is the highest y-value of the data? The data looks like this:

```
Score    Frame
0.2        1
3.6        2
4.56       3
0.3        4
2.8        5
1.7        6
3.5        7
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes, there definitely is a way. Please share a reproducible sample of data to help us answer though. If you already have a dataset, you can copy/paste the output of "dput(nameOfYourData)" into your question above.

Comment: Since there's a wide variety of ways to do this, it will also help in the future to include a description or image of what you want the output to look like.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a few of the many possible ways:

```
require(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(
  Score=c(0.2,3.6,4.56,0.3,2.8,1.7,3.5),
  Frame=c(1:7)
)
df$Max <- ifelse(df$Score==max(df$Score),"Yes","No")

ggplot(data=df, aes(x=Frame,y=Score)) +
  geom_point(aes(col=Max),size=2) +
  geom_line()
```

Option 1 output:

[image]

Or you can use something like:

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=Frame,y=Score)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_hline(yintercept = max(df$Score, na.rm=TRUE),
             color="red")
```

Option 2 output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One possibility would be to use size aesthetic as follows:

```
Graph<-ggplot(data=df, aes(x=Frame,y=Score)) +
  geom_point(aes(size=Score)) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]